# Setting up an average score leaderboard on GameCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

I'm trying to set up an average score leaderboard on gamecenter. I've been trying to see if there is some sort of native support for an average score but have been unable to find anything. Sending the locally calculated average score doesn't work because gamecenter either takes the highest score or the lowest score depending on what sort of leaderboard you set, but you can't set up a score that updates EVERY time.

Does anyone know a good solution?

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this?

Comment: Nope. I haven't look into it more recently, however.